# Django Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to build a community page that has both a form for posting a new post and a list of all the previous posts, similar to facebook. But now I keep getting the error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

This is my view function:

```
def community(request):
    if redirect_if_false_choice(request):
        return redirect_if_false_choice(request)
    posts = CommunityPost.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('date_posted')
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if str(request.method) == 'GET':
       return render(request, 'officer/community.html', {'posts': posts, 'form': form})
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       return redirect('community')
```

And this is the form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = CommunityPost
        fields = ('content', )
        widgets = {
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'placeholder': 
            "What's going on?"})
        }
```

The entire stacktrace:

```
Internal Server Error: /officer/community/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/security_officer_wanted/officer/views.py", line 114, in community
    return render(request, 'officer/community.html', {'posts': posts, 'form': form})
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 192, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-securityofficerwanted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/image_cropping/templatetags/cropping.py", line 18, in cropped_thumbnail
    ratiofield = instance._meta.get_field(ratiofieldname)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
[04/Jul/2019 06:18:57] "GET /officer/community/ HTTP/1.1" 500 169040
```

Comment: post the whole stacktrace

Comment: @Exprator added it

Comment: from the stacktrace I can see that you are using django_image-cropping and that error is coming from the templatetag. Can you post the html as well?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the code you posted, but is happening in the `croppwd_thimbnail` tag. You need to show the full template to see what is being passed to that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the mistake was that the site doesn't know who posted a post, I fixed that and now it works. 
(The template calls a function in the `CommunityPost` model that should return the user who posted the post. But since nobody posted it, it returned none.)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to be sure from the information you've provided.

The error reported to you, no doubt, mentions a line number which would be very informative and looking at it you could almost certainly divine what is meant. It's likely the line producing the error is inside the Django libraries, but you can follow the stack up in any sensible debugger to the point where your code calls on Django and scratch your head there.

That said one clear problem that *might* be related to what your experiencing is that your Meta class above is not a member of the PostForm class. See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

And try for example:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CommunityPost
        fields = ('content', )
        widgets = {
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'placeholder': "What's going on?"})
        }
```

But it strikes me that this might just as likely be a formatting mistake in your post here. Quite unsure. All I can say is, it looks wrong.

Comment: Did you see the stacktrace I added?

Comment: No, I hadn't. You can see in it though that at line 18 of .../site-packages/image_cropping/templatetags/cropping.py, instance is None. That's the error. But I've never used the [image cropping](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping) helper and can't comment. I can se that it's in a folder called templatetags and so likely relates to your template somehow. Do you need to use template tags to use that library? If so, look at those.